# Rendering taking a lot of time in blender 3.0

Tags: rendering, gpu

I started to render a scene in blender2.9 and it took around 15 min to render at 700 samples but then i started to render the same frame in blender 3.0 and it was showing around 1hr and that too at 128 samples . And i have kept the device to gpu compute. And also i  tried to choose the render device to optix but it doesn't allow me to while the earlier version allowed me to. Or is it because i am using a laptop gpu( rtx 3050 laptop gpu).
Is there any solution.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Try to reduce the Tile Size. Inside the Render Properties > Performance > Memory > Tile Size

Answer (score 0):

If you have Blender 2.9 and 3.0 installed simultaneously, they do not share settings. Therefore you have to enable OptiX rendering: `Edit` > `Preferences` > `System` > `Cycles render devices` > `OptiX`
Furthermore, it is likely that the other render settings differ from your 2.9 render setup. You could open the file in both Blender 2.9 and 3.0 and compare the settings side by side.

BTW: If you are using OptiX and denoising, you most likely won't need that many samples. I did a few comparison renders and it turned out that there is not much of a difference between 50 (!) and 200 samples. This depends on your overall scene (lights etc.), of course. But the OptiX denoiser seems to be pure magic :)